# How to remove lines from a large file

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a large file with each line of the form

`a b c`

I would like to remove all such lines where there does not exist another line either like

`b d e`

or `d a e`

with `abs(c - e) < 10`.

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` are all integers.

For example if the input is:

```
0 1 10 
1 2 20
2 3 25
0 1 15 
1 4 40
```

then the output should be

```
1 2 20
2 3 25
0 1 15
```

Is it possible to do this in anything like linear time?

One idea is to create two dictionaries of sorted lists. One for the third column values associated with first column values. The other for the third column values associated with second column values. Then when you see a b c, look up c in the sorted list you get using key a in the second dictionary and then c in the sorted list you get using key b in the first dictionary.

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: I would be surprised if this could be done in linear time. My guess for the minimum complexity would be O(N*Log(N))

Comment: @GamesBrainiac It is not homework.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac you sound like a cop dog that just smelled cocaine. Is homework illegal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this can be done in linear time.  It is straightforward to do it in O(n·log n) time if there are n triplets in the input.  Here is a sketch of a method, in a not-necessarily-preferred form of implementation:

1. Make an array of markers M, initially all clear.
2. Create an array and make a copy of the input, sorted first on the middle element and then by the third element whenever middle elements are equal.  (Time is O(n·log n) so far.)
3. For each distinct middle value, make a BST (binary search tree) with key = third element.  (Time is O(n·log n) again.)
4. Make a hash table keyed by middle values, with data pointing at appropriate BST's.  That is, given a middle value y and third element z, in time O(1) we can get to the BST for triplets whose middle value is y; and from that, in time O(log n) can find the triplet with third-element value closest to z.
5. For each triplet t = (x,y,z) in turn, if marker is not yet set use the hash table to find the BST, if any, corresponding to x.  In that BST, find the triplet u with third element closest to z.  If difference is less than 10, set the markers for t and u.  (Time is O(n·log n) again.)
6. Repeat steps 2–5 but with BST's based on first element values rather than middle value, and lookups in step 5 based on y rather than x.  (Although the matching-relations are symmetric, so that we can set two markers at each cycle in step 5, some qualifying triplets may end up not marked; ie, they are in tolerance but more distant than the nearest-match that is found.  It would be possible to mark all of the qualifying triplets in step 5, but that would increase worst-case time from O(n·log n) to O(n²·log n).)
7. For each marker that is set, output the corresponding triplet.

Overall time: O(n·log n).  The same time can be achieved without building BST's but instead using binary searches within subranges of the sorted arrays.

*Edit:* In python, one can build structures usable with *[bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)* as illustrated below in excerpts from an ipython interpreter session.  (There may be more efficient ways of doing these steps.)  Each data item in dictionary `h` is an array suitable for searching with `bisect`.

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: a=[(0,1,10), (1,2,20), (2,3,25), (0,1,15), (1,4,40), (1,4,33), (3,3,17), (2,1,19)]

In [3]: b=sorted((e[1],e[2],i) for i,e in enumerate(a)); print b
[(1, 10, 0), (1, 15, 3), (1, 19, 7), (2, 20, 1), (3, 17, 6), (3, 25, 2), (4, 33, 5), (4, 40, 4)]

In [4]: h={k:list(g) for k,g in groupby(b,lambda x: x[0])}; h
Out[4]: 
{1: [(1, 10, 0), (1, 15, 3), (1, 19, 7)],
 2: [(2, 20, 1)],
 3: [(3, 17, 6), (3, 25, 2)],
 4: [(4, 33, 5), (4, 40, 4)]}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to do this in python? Maybe bisect and a sorted list could replace the BSTs?

Comment: @phoenix, added example

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, linear time may not be possible. Here is an easy O(n^2) implementation. If you sort the lists inside the dictionaries, you should be able to improve the runtime.

```
lines = """0 1 10 
1 2 20
2 3 25
0 1 15 
1 4 40"""
Adata = {}
Bdata = {}
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    a,b,c = line.split(' ')[:3]
    vals = map(int,[a,b,c])
    if b in Adata:
        Adata[b].append(vals)
    else:
        Adata[b] = [vals]
    if a in Bdata:
        Bdata[a].append(vals)
    else:
        Bdata[a] = [vals]

def case1(a,b,c):
    if a in Adata:
        for val in Adata[a]:
            if abs(int(c)-val[2]) < 10:
                return True
    return False

def case2(a,b,c):
    if b in Bdata:
        for val in Bdata[b]:
            if abs(int(c)-val[2]) < 10:
                return True
    return False


out = []
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    a,b,c = line.split(' ')[:3]
    if case1(a,b,c) or case2(a,b,c):
        out.append(line)

for line in out:
    print line
```

Comment: Your code does not use case1 or case2. Is it just to give a general idea?

Comment: It does, scroll down.

Comment: Oops. Thanks. So maybe we just need to use bisect with a sorted list?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like

```
set lines
for line in infile:
  if line not in lines:
    lines.add(line)
    outfile.write(line)
```